# MYSQL select a value following three relations across tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a join for an application I am working on.

```
SELECT community.id, 
       community.name, 
       property.type, 
       property.lowest_price, 
       property.highest_price,
       property.commission_rate,
       property.fixed_bonus 
  FROM community, 
       property 
 WHERE community.zip IN ($zips) 
   AND property.community_id = community.id
```

I am looking to select an additional value that requires following three relations and am unsure the best way to do that.

The value I want to get is `builder_group.name`

The community table has `community.user_id` which correlates with the builder table `builder.user_id`

The builder table also has a `builder.builder_group_id` which correlates with the `builder_group` table's `builder_group.id`

The `builder_group` table finally has the value I want to select `builder_group.name`

Also, what is the best way to return the count for pagination purposes. Is it best to just do it once initially without returning columns and pass along at the PHP level or can it be returned with the SELECT without significant overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to explicit JOIN conditions, things become clearer:

```
SELECT community.id, community.name,
       property.type, property.lowest_price, property.highest_price, property.commission_rate, property.fixed_bonus,
       builder_group.name
FROM community
JOIN property      on property.community_id = community.id
JOIN builder       on builder.user_id = community.user_id
JOIN builder_group on builder_group.id = builder.builder_group_id
WHERE community.zip IN ($zips)
```

If you're worried about all those JOINs being slow then review the indexes on the columns involved in the join conditions (yet another reason to use explicit JOINs) and profile the query.

As far as your pagination question goes, You might want to read about the [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot more sense! Quick question though. Doing things this way, does that mean MYSQL has to build the whole table and then limit the results returned by zip?

Comment: @christian: That's up to the query optimizer but using explicit join conditions tells the optimizer exactly what your intent is so it can optimize better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT community.id, 
   community.name, 
   property.type, 
   property.lowest_price, 
   property.highest_price,
   property.commission_rate,
   property.fixed_bonus,builder_group.name
   FROM community 
   JOIN property ON property.community_id = community.id
   JOIN builder ON builder.user_id = community.user_id
   JOIN builder_group.id ON builder_group.id =  builder.builder_group_id 
   WHERE community.zip IN ($zips)
```